# BERT - Pass input to an intermediate layer

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

Let's say all layers in bert are frozen except the last one, and I have different bert models like this one trained for different purposes - thereby, having different weights for the last unfrozen layer, whilst having the same other layers. Now, passing inputs to all models will have redundancy as all layers except the last one are frozen, so their outputs will be the same for all. So, is there a way I can skip passing inputs for each model and instead get the outputs of the 11th layer(12total-1unfrozen) from 1 model and then pass those values as inputs to the 12th layer in the other models? If this is not possible, is there a way to break down bert layers so as to achieve this task?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. There are several ways to achieve something like that. What is your 12th layer? Is it an attention encoder of BERT that was pretrained?